# To move from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created Login.class and Dashboard.class. In Dashboard.class there are 4 fragment.class added. I cannot move to other activity after giving this code. Please help me by giving a solution.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: getapplicationcintext replace to refference to your current activity YOURACTIVITINAME.this

Comment: Your Dashboard class is fragment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add Dashboard activity class to your manifest?

I recommend don't use getApplicationContext()
in fragment you can call getActivity():

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Dashboard.class);
startActivity(i);
```